# Using density to prove the existence of continuous extensions, without the fact that open sets are countable unions of intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $E$ be a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Prove that there exists a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in E$.

Now by the above assumptions $E$ contains both it's supremum and infemum. Consider the set $V=[\sup E,\inf E]$ then $E\subseteq V$.
If $E$ is dense in $V$, define $$g(x) = \left\{
                  \begin{array}{ll}
                      f(x) & \mbox{if }\;x\in V \\
                      f(\sup E)  & \mbox{if }\;x\geq\sup E\\
                      f(\inf E)  & \mbox{if }\;x\leq\inf E
                      \end{array}
                 \right.$$
It is easy to show that $g$ is continuous.

If $E$ is not dense in $V$, define $S=\{x\in V\mid x$ is not a limit point of E $\}$. For each $p\in S$, define $A_p=\{x\in E\mid x<p\}$ and $B_p=\{x\in E\mid x>p\}$. Here is when I get stuck. I want to show that $\sup A_p\in A_p$ and $\inf B_p\in B_p$ which will allow us to define a straight line $\phi_p:[\sup A_p,\inf B_p]\to\mathbb{R}$ with the condition $\phi_p(\sup A_p)=f(\sup A_p)$ and $\phi_p(\inf B_p)=f(\inf B_p)$. Hence if we define $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as 
$$g(x) = \left\{
                  \begin{array}{ll}
f(\sup E)  & \mbox{if }\;x\geq\sup E\\
                      f(\inf E)  & \mbox{if }\;x\leq\inf E \\
                      f(x) & \mbox{if }\;x\in E \\
                      \phi_x(x) & \mbox{if }\;x\in S 
                      \end{array}
                 \right.$$

Can someone help? Don't forget that I don't want to use the fact that every open set of real numbers is the union of a countable
collection of disjoint open intervals.

Comment: I do not see how *density* is relevant to this problem.

Comment: $E$ is dense in $V$ if and only if $E=V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if $E$ is dense in $V$, then $E=V$ since $E$ is closed.
(Not clear from your post if you noticed that, just pointing out.)

Now (in general) for any $x$ do:
(a) if $x>\sup E$ then let $f(x)=f(\sup E)$ (just as you already did, 
(b) if $x<\inf E$ then let $f(x)=f(\inf E)$ (note also that instead of $\inf$ or $\sup$ we could write $\min$ or $\max$ since $E$ is compact), and
(c) (the more interesting case) $x\in(\inf E,\sup E)\setminus E$.
Then let $a_x=\sup \Bigr(E\cap [\inf E,x)\Bigr)$ and 
$b_x=\inf \Bigl(E\cap (x,\sup E]\Bigr)$.
Note that $a_x<x<b_x$ and $a_x,b_x\in E$.
Then $(a_x,b_x)$ is the largest open interval containing $x$ and missing $E$.
$f$ is defined at the endpoints $a_x,b_x$ of $[a_x,b_x]$ but needs to be defined for the interior points, $(a_x,b_x)$.
Extend $f$ as a linear function $\tilde f=y=px+q$ on $[a_x,b_x]$ for suitable $p,q$ subject to the condition $\tilde f(a_x)=f(a_x)$ and $\tilde f(b_x)=f(b_x)$.
Verify that this indeed works ($\tilde f$ is well-defined and continuous, and extends $f$).

Edit. This is what you are trying to do in your post anyway, but you say you do not see why $\sup A_p\in A_p$. Well, you may define $A_p$ in a slightly different way: $A_p=\{x\in E\mid x\le p\}=E\cap[\inf E,p]$. Then $A_p$ is closed (and bounded), hence $\sup A_p\in A_p$.
Also, $\sup A_p<p$ since there is an open interval $(p-\varepsilon_p,p+\varepsilon_p)$ missing $E$, hence missing $A_p$, hence $\sup A_p\le p-\varepsilon_p<p$.

Comment: I'm curious as to whether Mr Saleh is happy with this.  He wants to avoid knowing about component intervals of open sets, but your proof supplies a component interval of the complement of $E$ for each point not in $E$.

Comment: Okay @Mirko thank you for your time, this works. I'm happy with the fact I did not know about the countability of such components.